# which method is getting called when app is opened by push notification clicked

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios9

i just implement push notification in my application.
issue : while my application is off and i got push notification and when i clicked on it. i want to call one api so i want to know that by which method i can handle this.
Note: the main thing is app in closed state.

here is my code

```
if (application.applicationState == .Active)
    {
        print("Active")



    }
    else (application.applicationState == .Inactive)
    {
        print("InActive")
    }
```

but this code is only working when my app is active or iactive. how can i do this when my app is totally closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you application is closed and push notification is received and if you click on it, then `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called.

In that, you will get a special key to check that user has opened by clicking on push notification or not. You can check it via following way:

```
//Checking user has tapped on Notification or not!

if let dicTemp = launchOptions?["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] {
    //Notification Key Found
}
```

Comment: ok Thanks man its working for me.. once again thanks for help to new comers like me

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Can you tell me what does dicTemp contains ?

Comment: @MelanieJourne Please check for the updated answer. The variable `dicTemp` will check that key exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

For swift 3 you can check it the following way:

```
if let dicTemp = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] {
    //Notification Key Found
    print("Local Notification")
} else if let dicTemp = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
    print("Remote Notification")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way for normal push notifications to launch your app if it is not running.  There is an alternative, however, called Apple PushKit, which has been in beta for several years it seems.  It is -intended- to be used with VOIP applications to replace the "always leave a socket open" for handling incoming calls, but importantly, it WILL launch your app when your device receives a PushKit notification for it.

I have no idea if Apple will allow an app into the store that uses PushKit.

I have used it, (about a year ago), and it does work, but is buggy, and sometimes just stops accepting incoming notifications.